# Postgresql schemas and Delayed::Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, delayed-job, multi-tenant

I'm setting up a multi tenant Rails application with Postgresql schemas.

How can I scope the db search path for Delayed::Job?

This would work:

```
initializers/dj_config.rb:

Delayed::Job.class_eval do
 connection.schema_search_path = ["#{current_tenant}", "public"].join(",")
end
```

...but I need a way to pass in the current tenant, which seems hard since the DJ worker is a different process than the one where "current_tenant" is set. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and ended up creating custom job classes with `perform` methods that set the current_tenant. I simply passed the current_tenant into the constructor:

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue CustomJob.new(current_tenant)
```